# Does Discord.net have something like count of members in voice chat?

Tags: discord.net

i need count of members in voice chat how can i do this without iterating over each for is user joined or not and making array with it. And pls does discord.net have events which fires on update of voice chat

Answer (score 1):

[SocketVoiceChannel#Users](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketVoiceChannel.html#Discord_WebSocket_SocketVoiceChannel_Users) will give you a collection of users currently in a voice channel.

[SocketClient.UserVoiceStateUpdated](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_UserVoiceStateUpdated) will give you when a user joins, leaves, or moves voice channels.